# Invalid grouped property access

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlcomponent

In this qml code:

```
Component {      
  id: userdelegate
  PictureBox {
    ...
    icon: model.icon
    icon.heigth: 50
  }
}
```

`PictureBox` comes from the `PictureBox.qml` system file in this way:

```
...
Image {
  id: icon
  ...
  width: parent.width; height: 150
}
```

Running qml, I have the error in the title.
I need to use `PictureBox.qml`, but I can't change it.
How can I override default height value for `PictureBox.qml` icon?

Comment: I think the only way is using [aliases](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-attributes). But you said you cannot change PictureBox.qml :-O

Comment: I don't see an `icon` property anywhere in that code ("`PictureBox.qml`"). Can you post code that's actually relevant for the question?

Comment: @Mitch: icon is the id of Image element.

Comment: @cloc3 `Image` doesn't have an `icon` property. You'll have trouble getting a correct answer if your question is incomplete.

Comment: ok. This was my mystake. so I need to access the height property of Image element by id. how may i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to bypass QML's scoping rules by traversing Item children until you can find the Image and manipulate it directly. It's possible it could break in the future, but `item.toString()` gives you something useful:

```
item.toString() -> "QQuickImage(0x114054350)"
```

So, you can try something like this (not tested):

```
function findItemOfType(type, item) {
    if (item.toString().indexOf(type) != -1) {
        return child;
    }
    for (var i=0;i < children.length;++i) {
        var child = children[i];
        var result = findItemOfType(type, child.children);
        if (result != null) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Using it like this:

```
findItemOfType("QQuickImage", pictureBoxId);
```